# How to get input value upon button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

What I am trying to do is, upon clicking the Submit button, I want to grab the value that was typed into the input to then update the h1.

```
import React from "react";

function App() {
  const [headingText, setHeadingText] = React.useState("");

  function handleChange(event) {
    setHeadingText(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    alert(event.target);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h1>Hello {headingText}</h1>
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="text"
          placeholder="What's your name?"
          value={headingText}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

With the above code, so far I am able to update the h1 after every single keystroke that is entered into the input. But instead of that, I want to *only* update the h1 with the input value *when I press the Submit button*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use 2 `useState`'s, one to hold the value of the input box, the other to hold the value of the header.

```js
// import React from "react"; // not On StackOverflow

function App() {
  const [headingTextBuffer, setHeadingTextBuffer] = React.useState("");
  const [headingText, setHeadingText] = React.useState("");

  function handleChange(event) {
    setHeadingTextBuffer(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    setHeadingText(headingTextBuffer);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h1>Hello {headingText}</h1>
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="text"
          placeholder="What's your name?"
          value={headingTextBuffer}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

// export default App; // not on StackOverflow

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Going to try this now

Comment: I had a couple of typos, click "Run code snippet" to see in action

Comment: No worries--I noticed the typos--no big deal! Thx!

Comment: Btw, this also updates when you press `enter`/`return` on your keyboard due to the `<form>` tag

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is using an `inputText` state that is updated in your `handleChange` function.

Now when you submit in your submit function you can update the `headingText` state to be equal to the `inputText` which should update your `h1` value.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the result of each keystroke in the state in another field that is not displayed anywhere and on click put the value from that new field into the heading. Like this :

```
import React from "react";

function App() {
  const [tempHeadingText, setTempHeadingText] = React.useState("");
  const [headingText, setHeadingText] = React.useState("");

  function handleChange(event) {
    setTempHeadingText(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    setHeadingText(tempHeadingText);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h1>Hello {headingText}</h1>
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="text"
          placeholder="What's your name?"
          value={tempHeadingText}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```